# Access token validation failure. Invalid audience requesting AzureADPolicies

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, policy

Im using powershell to connect to azure ad and what I need is to get a list of the policies that were configured.

First, I used `Connect-azuread` to get into my tenant, and when I tryed to use `Get-AzureADPolicy`, I'm having this error:

Get-AzureADPolicy: Error occurred while executing GetPolicies  Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Message: Access token validation failure. Invalid audience. InnerError:
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 20:36:13 GMT HttpStatusCode: Unauthorized HttpStatusDescription: Unauthorized HttpResponseStatus: Completed

any ideas of what could I been doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment. I was able to get the list of policies successfully.

[image: Command Output]

Try using `AzureADPreview` latest module

```
Uninstall-Module AzureAD 

Install-Module AzureADPreview 

Import-Module AzureADPreview
```

Now, use cmdlet “`Connect-AzureAD`”   with credentials and “`Get-AzureADPolicy`” to display the list of policies.

If still the error remains, please check if you have permissions and granted consent for the same.

Try with "Connect-AzureAD -AzureEnvironmentName AzureUSGovernment"

**Reference**:

[Get-AzureADDirectorySetting - Authintication problems - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/422925/get-azureaddirectorysetting-authintication-problem.html)